# Force particular Java version in particular directory

Tags: jdk, ubuntu-12.10

I have multiple versions of java installed on my machine (5,6,7). I downloaded a project which requires jdk6 to compile. Is there a way to 'set' jdk6 to be the default one in that particular directory?

Modifying the makefiles is out of question - way too complex)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the system wide default jdk, compile and then reveryt back to the one you were using before.

```
# update-alternatives --config java              # Select java-1.6.0-oracle
# update-java-alternatives --set java-1.6.0-oracle
```